# Ag Grid cell render if statement

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to use cell render to check conditions on a cell in the grid. I found this snippet of code which does something similar using Angular. I'm trying to recreate using React and wonder if anyone can help.

If the the athlete field equals 'Bolt' then in the 'age' column this should display '35'

```html
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Athlete", field: "athlete", width: 150, cellRenderer: athleteCellRendererFunc},
    {headerName: "Age", field: "age", width: 90},
     ];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    angularCompileRows: true
};

 function athleteCellRendererFunc(row) {
        if(row.data.athlete == 'Bolt')
        {
           return '<span ng-bind="data.age">'35'</span>';
        }
        else
        {
           return '<span ng-bind="data.age"></span>';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom cell renderer for your need. e.g.

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
  const ageValue = props.data.athlete.toLowerCase().includes('michael') ? '35': '';

  return (
      <span>{ageValue}</span>
  );
};
```

check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uLTPYzE3txzkb9ZD?open=index.jsx)
Also you can find more about cell rendered on [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/)